# Check some column's values between them in pandas and make a list of ID belonging to that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my sample data.
Data contains, ID, North, East and other headers in tuple format

```
ID,North,East,"(6640.83, 679.0)","(6648.84, 673.37)","(6649.83, 674.3)","(6647.0, 200.0)"
1,6642.83,679.37,2.0,8.4,8.6,479.38
1,6648.84,673.37,9.7,0.0,1.3,473.3
2,6649.83,674.3,10.1,1.3,1.4,474.3
2,6647.0,200.0,3.03,473.3,474.30,5.0
```

My target is to check each columns data except `'ID','North' and 'East'`) by each row and see who has the minimum value. And when i find the minimum value, then I would like to write that such values (Only ID) in a list belonging to that column

for example, row 1 has lowest value belonging to column `"(6640.83, 679.0)"`
then,
I would like to make a list of

```
6640.83_679.0 = [1] # here 1 value comes from the ID of that row.
```

and it continues. For example, row 4 has again the minimum value belonging to `"(6640.83, 679.0)"`, then instead of creating separate list belonging to that column, i would like to use the same created list and add the ID == 2
eg. Basically if there is already a list exist belonging to that column, then I dont want to create again another list but if there is no list created previously belonging to that column, then I would like to create the list, so that I can store value, 
Now, the previous list becomes like this

```
6640.83_679.0 = [1, 2] # value corresponding to first rows and 4th rows of id of 1 and 2
6648.87_673.37 = [1] # value corresponding to second rows but has ID of 1
6649.83_674.3 = [2] # value corresponding to third rows and has ID of 2
```

I dont want to use `np.where` and check with each column because it is possible that those column which needs to be checked can be over 50 columns.

Is there possible to achieve this using pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest create dictionary instead lists:

```
#filter only tuples columns
df1 = df.iloc[:, 3:]
print (df1)
   (6640.83, 679.0)  (6648.84, 673.37)  (6649.83, 674.3)  (6647.0, 200.0)
0              2.00                8.4               8.6           479.38
1              9.70                0.0               1.3           473.30
2             10.10                1.3               1.4           474.30
3              3.03              473.3             474.3             5.00

#get positions by min values
s = pd.Series(df1.values.argmin(axis=1) + 1, index=df1.index)
print (s)
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    1
dtype: int64

#get column names (tuples) by min values
m = df1.idxmin(axis=1)
print (m)
0     (6640.83, 679.0)
1    (6648.84, 673.37)
2    (6648.84, 673.37)
3     (6640.83, 679.0)
dtype: object

#create dictioanry of lists
d = s.groupby(m).apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{'(6640.83, 679.0)': [1, 1], '(6648.84, 673.37)': [2, 2]}

#for select value of dict (if tuples omit '')
print (d['(6640.83, 679.0)'])
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much :)

Comment: isnt the final output wouldbe like this
`{'(6640.83, 679.0)': [1,2 ] # that is first and 4th row of having ID 1 and 2 respectively , '(6648.84, 673.37)': [1, 2]} # that is second and 3rd row of having ID 1 and 2 respectively`.

Comment: because first two rows has ID of 1 each and next two has ID of 2 each

Comment: yes 3.03 is minimum value and its corresponds to the column `(6640.83, 679.0)`, so that dictionary would be `{'(6640.83, 679.0)': [1,2 ]`, i.e first row and the 4th row of id 1 and 2 :)

Comment: @user3280146 - For first row is min `2` in first column, for second `0` is is second column, for third is it `1.3` it is second column and for last it is `3.03` it is first column. Or it is different?

Comment: sorry, it has little bit messy data. If I couldnt make you clear, maybe we could do chat. I can write another sample dataframe for it :)

Comment: It hasnt given me option to lets continue this discussion to chat.  Is it okay, if i create another public room and invite you there ?

Comment: @user3280146 - sure

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178913/check-some-columns-values-between-them-in-pandas-and-make-a-list-of-id-belonging